# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magentouser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi I am trying to connect my MySQL database with my Magento site in xampp local host. but did't connect. I am a beginner of mysql server system . please help me how to connect step by step.

Comment: The error message is quite self explanatory: either the username or the password was incorrect.

Comment: Please DON'T ask for a tutorial, consider trying harder and leaving more data like PHP connection to database lines...